# When I run the Codename One HelloWorld Java Program from the Codename One HelloWorld Tutorial, I get an error

Tags: java, codenameone

When I run the Codename One HelloWorld Java Program from the Codename One HelloWorld Tutorial video, I get this error:
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Button
location: class com.acmecorp.appname.AppName

I think I'm missing an import for class Button.  How do I add the import statement for class Button so that the compilation won't have this error?

Here is my source code:

```
package com.acmecorp.appname;


import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.io.NetworkEvent;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class AppName {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        // use two network threads instead of one
        updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

        addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevent the event from propagating
            err.consume();
            if(err.getError() != null) {
                Log.e(err.getError());
            }
            Log.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
        });        
    }
    
    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        Button b = new Button("Show Dialog");
        hi.add(b);
        b.addActionListener((e) -> Dialog.show("Dialog Title", "Hi", "OK", null));
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Judging from the other imports, I'd make an educated guess and say `import com.codename1.ui.Button;` should do the trick.

Comment: Also [this](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Button.html) is the first result I got by searching "codenameone button" on duckduckgo (and google, for that matter...). Did you try that before asking?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Federico!  That fixed the error.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this **com.codename1.ui.Button** might works for u.